# How to use mocaps in your game if they don't loop smoothly?

Tags: 3d, graphics, animation

Following suggestions on IRC, I've downloaded, parsed and incorporated the [Free Release of 2500 mocaps](http://www.cgspeed.com/) to my game. I've noticed, though, that none of those loop perfectly. It does not connect and thus won't form proper walking/jumping/etc cycles. So how I'm supposed to use them in my game? Is there a tool or some trick to solve that problem I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the artist’s approach and the engine programmer’s approach.

What an animator would do is rework the animation sequences in an application such as [MotionBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_MotionBuilder), [Maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Maya), or even the free [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29). The animating features of these tools are quite tricky to use at first, but there are plenty of tutorial videos on the web to get started.

Another method would be to use software blending: dynamically compute a pose that is a blend of the first and last frames of the animation sequence, then add a blend-out from that frame at the beginning of the animation, and a blend-in to that frame at the end. That way, the sequences will always loop properly, though the result won’t probably be as good as if tweaked by a skilled human.